# Dell T5500 Graphics card to use have a card on hand

Tags: workstation

Question that I have that I cant seem to find out.

I Have a **Dell T5500** on the way for a project of mine.

I bought it without a Graphics card.

According to the Online Sources it needs one to boot.

I have a [MSI Radeon 6870](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127545) on hand will this card work in the System or will *I need to buy a different card*?

The Specs say **PCI Express 2.1 x16**

and I know the tower says **2.0 x16**

Note:I have read that PCI Express slots are forward and backward compatible just want to know if I will be able to use this card to get an OS installed.

So what would anyone recommend if I cant use this card I want the Cheapest route of a card I could drop in this. I just want to be able to remote in to the system Once setup.

Comment: According to this [spec sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-Precision-T5500-SpecSheet.pdf) it has an nVidia GPU on the motherboard.

Comment: Awesome so I may not need to install a Graphics card to install an os to remote off of if this is correct.

Comment: That would be my guess. If it turns out not to be the case, then the Radeon should be sufficient.

Comment: Well thanks for your help I will let you know once it arrives with either case. If not I will pick up something cheap to get it booted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the embedded graphics do not work, your graphics card should work fine. PCI-E is fully backwards compatible, so your 2.1 video card will function just fine in a 2.0 slot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it turns up in searches, so new information may be useful to some...

I have had a Dell Precision Workstation T5500 since 2013.

Both an ATI Radeon HD 7850 and now a nVidia Quadro P2000 have worked perfectly in it.

-Noel